# how to replace space in image url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, url

I am fetching data from an api and it contains image urls. When i try to display the images it is not showing any picture. when i logged using  `console.log(service.coverImage)`, i was able to display the image urls. for example

```
https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ererf3wery/Hillside Plaza Hotel 5cdebeaf34157a0026526f0d/providerImage/hph.jpeg
```

You notice the link breaks and it doesn't go to the image directly, now i cannot change this in the database. How can i solve this in Nodejs to replace the places so that it becomes complete.

I have used methods like `replace` and `encodeURIComponent` but not helping
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image url looks fine, if you are not able to see the image in web page, try to remove protocol from it.

```
url = url.replace("https:", "");
```

If that doesn't work, then try removing spaces as you wanted:

```js
let url = "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ererf3wery/Hillside Plaza Hotel-5cdebeaf34157a0026526f0d/providerImage/hph.jpeg";
url = url.replace(/\ /g, "%20");
console.log(url)
```

Comment: there i get an error. i want to replace the space with %20

Comment: Updated, have a look

Comment: it gets a valid url though in the end returns and error TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null because the initial request had null value before the replace